# How can I read the window title with JNI or JNA?

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface, swig, jna

Looking to get back into the development space; primarily using Java to call some native win32 functions (I don't desire to build in .NET)....

Can someone point me to a place where I can read the title from a differnt running window using Java (JNI/JNA/SWIG). Assume you would know where in the memory space the application you are attempting to hook into is.

Answer (score 9):

In JNA:

```
public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

    int GetWindowTextA(PointerType hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
}
```

To use it:

```
byte[] windowText = new byte[512];

PointerType hwnd = ... // assign the window handle here.
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, windowText, 512);
System.out.println(Native.toString(windowText));
```

You'll probably want to use the proper structure mappings for HWND and also allow unicode support; you can find that information and more examples on how to do that at the [JNA website](https://github.com/twall/jna/).

The documentation for GetWindowText function is available here in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Documentation for JNA is available at [jna.dev.java.net](https://github.com/twall/jna/)

Comment: how can i get a Window Handle?