# Bring window to front from Java

Tags: java, dll, window, desktop

Is there any way to bring a window to the front using Java? Maybe using some operating system library?

Comment: please correct the title

Comment: what do you mean by activating a window , can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I fixed title, I think he means to bring a window to front, but I am not sure..

Comment: He probably wants to call Win32's SetForegroundWindow from Java. JNI anyone ?

Comment: If "windows" is something that inherits `java.awt.Window`, `toFront` method brings it to the front of another windows in the current JVM.

Comment: This is an unanswerable question as it is currently written.

Comment: Is "a window" referring to one that you have created and have control over in your program? Or is "a window" some random window on the same computer? Or are you asking about home automation software to open "a window" in your house?

Comment: Yes, i mean to bring a window to front, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Hi Nate, i mean to some random window on the same computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it is possible, but then your solution would be very OS specific.

Theoretically it can be done by placing a call to win32 API in the following sequence:

1. [FindWindow Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(v=VS.85).aspx)
2. [ShowWindow  Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(v=VS.85).aspx) OR,
3. [BringWindowToTop Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673(v=VS.85).aspx)

Now the problem comes 'how to call them from java?'. Well all the above functions are defined in `user32.dll` and it can be accessed by [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/).

Some sample references to user32 API using JNA are:

1. [How can I read the window title with JNI or JNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173926/java-jni-jna-get-window-title)
2. [call FindWindow method of User32.dll using java](http://javadevelopersdiary.blogspot.com/2008/03/call-findwindow-method-of-user32dll.html)

Use google to find more.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Favonius, I'll prove it.

Comment: Can you plz tell that how can we know which DLL is doing which kind of functions? is there any way to know it?

Answer (score 2):

```html
package focus;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class ForegroundWindow {
 private interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
  final User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

  boolean SetForegroundWindow(HWND handle);

  HWND FindWindowA(String className, String windowName);

  HWND GetForegroundWindow();
 }

 private String getWindowName(String winName) {
  String winText = "";
  if (winText.contains(winName)) {
   return winText;
  }
  return null;
 }

 public boolean bringWindowToFront(String className, String winName) {
  HWND hWnd = User32.instance.FindWindowA(className, getWindowName(winName));
  if (hWnd == null) {
   return false;
  }
  return User32.instance.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SWT is nice for Win32 calls.

import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")

int hwnd = OS.FindWindowW(null, "Titlein".toCharArray());